# ceres shared library ubuntu failed

Tags: ubuntu, shared-libraries

I have ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS xenial and i want to install ceres, but not as static library. I want install it as shared library.
I followed the instructions via this link: http://ceres-solver.org/installation.html, but when i add following commands
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bzindovic/suitesparse-bugfix-1319687
sudo apt-get update
after update it shows me:
...
Err:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/bzindovic/suitesparse-bugfix-1319687/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
...
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/bzindovic/suitesparse-bugfix-1319687/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
...
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

I have amd, 64 bit, what i could do to install suitesparse (ceres) as a shared library.
I dont want to reinstall ubuntu to older, newest version,...

Answer (score 1):

It seems the mentioned documentation for installation and setup of ceres-solver is a bit old. The following is sufficient to add the required libsuitesparse-dev library.

```
sudo apt install libsuitesparse-dev
```

There's no need to add the repo with bugfix.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that PPA is for Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty Tahr), and was last updated like 250 weeks ago, that wouldn't work for you, so you have to source install suitesparse which has been mentioned in the link you provided http://ceres-solver.org/installation.html.

> Up to at least Ubuntu 14.04, the SuiteSparse package in the official package repository (built from SuiteSparse v3.4.0) cannot be used to build Ceres as a shared library. Thus if you want to build Ceres as a shared library using SuiteSparse, **you must perform a source install of SuiteSparse** or use an external PPA (see bug report here). It is recommended that you use the current version of SuiteSparse (4.2.1 at the time of writing).

download sources from [here](https://github.com/jluttine/suitesparse), then do:

```
cd your_download_dir/SuiteSparse-X.X.X/SuiteSparse/
```

now if you want to install the libraries, demos and include the headers:

```
make
```

or to compile just the libraries, do:

```
make library
```

or implement whatever suits you as described in the README.txt [here](https://github.com/jluttine/suitesparse)

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: @Dwhitz , thank you for clarifying, i will edit the answer.